# MongoCXX 3.4 - Using a unix domain socket URI

Tags: c++, mongodb, unix-socket, mongo-cxx-driver

I am trying to connect to MongoDB via the c++ driver. If I provide the IP based URI everything works fine, however when I try to use a unix domain socket URI I get the following error:

`an invalid MongoDB URI was provided`

I am trying to connect in the following way:

```
mongocxx::uri uri{"mongodb:///tmp/mongodb-27017.sock"};                                  
mongocxx::pool *p = new mongocxx::pool (uri);
```

If I replace the uri string with `mongodb://localhost:27017/?minPoolSize=0&maxPoolSize=10`, it works just fine.

I am probably doing something wrong, not sure what though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a trailing `/`. Try `mongocxx::uri uri{"mongodb:///tmp/mongodb-27017.sock/"};`.

Comment: Alternatively, URI encode: `mongodb://%2Ftmp%2Fmongodb-27017.sock`